# Reference for loop space objects

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Okay so, hi!

I would need to have some discussion related to loop space objects in a project of mine, but the only reference I can find for loop space objects is https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/loop+space+object and I would prefer having some actually published paper or even some online notes or basically anything, as long as it's more "official" than nlab, so I can cite it as a source. Things would be all nice if the setting was topological, but I need these for a category more general than $\textbf{Top}_*$... So, I would really appreciate it if someone could give any hints to where I could find something on them. My skills at googling have failed me... Oh, and something to emphasise: I am interested in the based loop space object, not the free one!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about Lurie's _Higher algebra_? He defines the loop functor $\Omega$ quite early, since it is needed to define stability.

Comment: @ZhenLin thank you! I will take a look at that and see if it has what I need!